# Command-line tool to get "click and drag" rectangle coordinates from the screen

Tags: xdotool, wmctrl

I would like to execute a command-line command that activates "click and drag" mouse selection on a single local X11 screen.

The goal is to:

- get the selected rectangle **X** and **Y** coordinates,
- get the rectangle **width** and **height**,
- output these values to **stdout**,
- (optional) draw a selection border while dragging the mouse.

Comment: Do you mean you want to move the mouse, as in "click and drag", to draw a rectangle on the desktop, and have some program then tell you what its size is?

Comment: @Gypsy Spellweaver, yes the rectangle can simply be outlines. does not have to be a filled box. I want the size of it ( in pixels ) also.. if it can include the X and Y coordinates on the screen. that would be extra help.

Comment: Perhaps soon as the rectangle drawn is complete.. the rectangle can disappear.. and I can return to the command prompt to see the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple tool is the `import` command from ImageMagick. Simply provide an output filename:

```
$ import /tmp/out.png
```

and it will grab the mouse and show an appropriate cursor. Press button 1 and drag out a rectangle which will be shown as a wire frame. Let go and the file will be created. You can get the info from this file:

```
$ identify /tmp/out.png
/tmp/out.png PNG 1515x14 1920x1080+24+15 ...
```

The rectangle in this example was 1515 by 14 pixels, with top-left offset of 24 and 15 on the screen.

To extract a [geometry string](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6):

```
$ identify /tmp/out.png | perl -ne '/ (\d+x\d+) \d+x\d+([-+]\d+[-+]\d+) / and print "$1$2\n"'
1515x14+24+15
```

Everything in one line:

```
import PNG:- | identify PNG:- | perl -ne '/ (\d+x\d+) \d+x\d+([-+]\d+[-+]\d+) / and print "$1$2\n"'
```

Or just with ImageMagick (no perl, sed, grep, awk, etc.)
and using native ImageMagick format:

```
import MIFF:- | convert MIFF:- -format "%wx%h%X%Y\n" info:
```

EDIT: It works even without piping to convert, so:

```
import -format "%wx%h%X%Y\n" info:
```