# Select area on screen with pointer

Tags: command-line, desktop, utilities

Is there a command line tool that let one select an area with pointer and print the result to terminal?

Much like with various screen capture tools, but I want the coordinates.

For example `x,y,width,height` or rect structure as in `left,top,right,bottom`

Comment: are you talking about capturing text?

Comment: You should use `scrot`. (No, I'm not making that name up).

Comment: Are you talking about gpm a mouse cursor for the command line? It allows you to select a text area and paste the result to the terminal using the middle button.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify are you trying to capture the contents of a terminal or part of the graphics screen, if graphics what is your specific environment? If terminal in which program are you using, vi, emacs, bash prompt , ... ?

Comment: See also [Command-line tool to get "click and drag" rectangle coordinates from the screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347849/80216).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`slop` application](https://github.com/naelstrof/slop) provides this functionality.

It supports selecting an arbitrary area or a particular window, and allows for changing the appearance of the selection box.

To use it, either click and drag to select a rectangular area, or click once on a window to select its area.
The rectangle corresponding to the selected area will then be written to `stdout`.

An example of the default output format is `200x100+500+400`, which indicates that a 200x100 rectangular area was selected, with its top left corner at the coordinate (500, 400).

Answer (score 3):

A minimal option is [`xrectsel`](https://github.com/ropery/xrectsel). It is available on Arch Linux through [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xrectsel).

Allows you to draw a simple rect on screen and outputs the following:

```bash
$ xrectsel
1643x627+564+445
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to xrectsel and slop, there is also [hacksaw](https://github.com/neXromancers/hacksaw),
but myself, I'm using this pure ImageMagick solution:

```
import -format "%wx%h%X%Y\n" info:
```